# I need to append multiple table from multiple DB dynamically in same Azure SQL DB Server (Cloud)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have 98 database and 352 tables in each database. All the database have same table schema. I have to append dynamically all the tables to a single destination database.

```
CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE AppendTablesDynamically
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(max),@DatabaseName NVARCHAR(max),@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- loop through all the tables in all the databases
    DECLARE curTables CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  TABLE_NAME AS TableName,TABLE_CATALOG AS DatabaseName
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    OPEN curTables
    FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @TableName, @DatabaseName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- build the SQL statement to append the table
        SET @SQL ='use' 'SELECT * into '+'merged_db.dbo.new_' +@TableName+ '  FROM '+  @TableName

       -- execute the SQL statement
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL




       FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @TableName, @DatabaseName
    END

   CLOSE curTables
    DEALLOCATE curTables
END





EXEC AppendTablesDynamically
```

Comment: Why do you have 98 databases?

Comment: I *hope* the reason you want to do this is to fix your design; if not it should be.

Comment: Did you notice that `SELECT * INTO...` only works the first time around? It creates tables to insert data, it won't insert into existing tables.

Comment: in azure sql you cant query cross database.

Comment: from my understanding you need to use other services to achieve your requirements like ADF.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two databases with the same schema and tables.
named  **“source_db1”**  and  **"source_db2"**

[image]

Below is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sample_table]
    ([id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [age] [int] NULL)
```

The Target/destination table is merged_db
Created the  **new_SampleTable**  With the same schema

Created stored procedure

```
create  PROCEDURE AppendTablesDynamically
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(max),@DatabaseName NVARCHAR(max),@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- loop through all the tables in all the databases
    DECLARE curTables CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  TABLE_NAME AS TableName,TABLE_CATALOG AS DatabaseName
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_CATALOG IN ('source_db1', 'source_db2')
    OPEN curTables
    FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @TableName, @DatabaseName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- this SQL statement is bult to append the table
        SET @SQL ='SELECT * into merged_db.dbo.new_' +@TableName+ '  FROM '+ @DatabaseName+'.dbo.'+@TableName

        -- execute the SQL statement
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

        FETCH NEXT FROM curTables INTO @TableName, @DatabaseName
    END

    CLOSE curTables
    DEALLOCATE curTables
END
```

[image]
[image]
This will loop through all the tables in all the databases and append them to the destination database.